# ML-1740 printer under Ubuntu 13.10 (64-bit) doesn't install

Tags: 13.10

I'm trying to install Samsung ML-1740 printer under Ubuntu 13.10 (64-bit). I use the Linux driver from this site:

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/ML-1740/XAA

Fresh Ubuntu 13.10 requires to add two components:

`libqt3-mt_3.3.8-b-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb` and

`libstdc++5_3.3.6-25ubuntu4_amd64.deb`.

When I run installation program there is a warning about missing component:

```
SANE - "Scanner Access Now Easy" - scanner API
```

Even though I think I have it installed:

Ubuntu Software Center lists `Simple Scan` version simple-scan `3.10.0-0ubuntu1`.

When I try and click `Install Anyway` it looks as if everything was installed OK.

> Unified Linux Driver is installed. Please, re-logon your system for
>   all the installation settings to take effect.

message is shown at the end. After re-logging there is no printer under:

`System Settings -> Printers`.

Same driver worked under Ubuntu 11 (I think 64-bit) and 12 (64-bit).

Does anyone have any ideas? Are there any log files I can analyze?

Thank you in advance.

Thompsonik

Answer (score 0):

You simply installed the driver. Now go to System Settings > Printers > Add and tell the system if you have a serial port printer, a USB printer, a network printer, etc. and, when prompted, select your Samsung and then ML-1740 and use the driver you installed.

Comment: Yep. That's exactly right. Ubuntu 12 did it automatically, in 13.10 you have to do it manually. Thanks for your help.